# How to create a straight tube shape into a circle animation in blender?

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

I'm learning Blender, so I can use it to make electricity animation videos. I have been trying to turn a straight line with one end into a circle.
Who knows how to achieve this animation effect?
[image]

Comment: it has already been answered and bendy bones seems to be the answer

Answer (score 4):

Move the origin of a cylinder to one end like this:

[image]

give it enough subdivision/loop cuts.

add simple deform modifier bend like this:

[image]

animate angle value and....

result:

[image]

[image]